# How to connect tornado app with php-script via fastcgi?

Tags: php, fastcgi, tornado

I whant to use tornado as front-end server for support websocket protocol. And i need transfer request from clients to my php backend.

Is there a way to implement it without using the queue?

The only thing I could think is use iostream to connect with php-fpm. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Just put php-fpm behind Nginx or Apache and use Tornado's http client.

Comment: Hmm, interesting idea - I'll try. Tnx